# Aligning table at left

Tags: tables, positioning

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{tabular}{ cc | *{16}{p{0.1in}} }
            &  &$(1)$ &$(2)$ &$(3)$ &$(4)$ &$(5)$ &$(6)$ &$(7)$ &$(8)$ &$(9)$ &$(10)$ &$(11)$ &$(12)$ &$(13)$ &$(14)$ &$(15)$ &$(16)$\\
            &   &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$1$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$1$\\
            &   &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$  &$1$ &$1$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$1$ &$1$ &$1$ &$1$\\
            &   &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$1$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$1$ &$1$ &$1$\\
            &   &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$1$ &$1$\\
            &   &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$\\ \hline
            &$-0000$\; $A$ &$\times$ & & &$\times$ & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
            &$1000-$\; $B$ & & & &$\times$ & & &$\times$ & & & & & & & & &\\
            &$01-01$\; $C$ & & & & & &$\times$ & & &$\times$ & & & & & & &\\
            &$10-01$\; $D$ & & & & & & &$\times$ & & & &$\times$ & & & & &\\
            &$011-1$\; $E$ & & & & & & & & &$\times$ & & & & &$\times$ & &\\
            &$111-0$\; $F$ & & & & & & & & & & & & &$\times$ & &$\times$ &\\
            &$00--0$\; $G$ &$\times$ &$\times$ &$\times$ & &$\times$ & & & & & & & & & & &\\
            &$0--10$\; $H$ & &$\times$ & & &$\times$ & & &$\times$ & &$\times$ & & & & & &\\
            &$-1-10$\; $I$ & & & & & & & &$\times$ & &$\times$ & &$\times$ & & &$\times$ &\\
            &$-111-$\; $J$ & & & & & & & & & &$\times$ & & & &$\times$ &$\times$ &$\times$\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{flushleft}
    \caption{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The table is aligned in the same place whatever command I use (`flushleft`,`center`). But if it is moved slightly to the left, it won't break the page margin. Is there any way to do it? Or is it happening due to the table size?

Also I need a total of 17 columns. But in order to do it, I am required to enter an extra `c` at the very beginning in `\begin{tabular}`. Means a total of 18 `c`s. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should fit into the avaliable space:

[image]

(Red lines inidcate margins)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\small
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.25pt}
  \[
    \begin{array}{@{}c l|*{16}{c}@{}}
            &   & (1) &(2) &(3) &(4) &(5) &(6) &(7) &(8) &(9) &(10) &(11) &(12) &(13) &(14) &(15) &(16)\\
            &   & 0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &1 &1\\
            &   & 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0  &1 &1 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1\\
            &   & 0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1 &1\\
            &   & 0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1\\
            &   & 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1\\ \hline
      -0000 & A &\times & & &\times & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
      1000- & B & & & &\times & & &\times & & & & & & & & &\\
      01-01 & C & & & & & &\times & & &\times & & & & & & &\\
      10-01 & D & & & & & & &\times & & & &\times & & & & &\\
      011-1 & E & & & & & & & & &\times & & & & &\times & &\\
      111-0 & F & & & & & & & & & & & & &\times & &\times &\\
      00--0 & G &\times &\times &\times & &\times & & & & & & & & & & &\\
      0--10 & H & &\times & & &\times & & &\times & &\times & & & & & &\\
      -1-10 & I & & & & & & & &\times & &\times & &\times & & &\times &\\
      -111- & J & & & & & & & & & &\times & & & &\times &\times &\times\\
    \end{array}
  \]
  \caption{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

If you prefer equally wide columns, decrease the font size, for example as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.75pt}
  \[
    \begin{array}{@{}c l|*{16}{wc{\widthof{(16)}}}@{}}
            &   & (1) &(2) &(3) &(4) &(5) &(6) &(7) &(8) &(9) &(10) &(11) &(12) &(13) &(14) &(15) &(16)\\
            &   & 0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &1 &1\\
            &   & 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0  &1 &1 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1\\
            &   & 0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1 &1\\
            &   & 0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1\\
            &   & 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1\\ \hline
      -0000 & A &\times & & &\times & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
      1000- & B & & & &\times & & &\times & & & & & & & & &\\
      01-01 & C & & & & & &\times & & &\times & & & & & & &\\
      10-01 & D & & & & & & &\times & & & &\times & & & & &\\
      011-1 & E & & & & & & & & &\times & & & & &\times & &\\
      111-0 & F & & & & & & & & & & & & &\times & &\times &\\
      00--0 & G &\times &\times &\times & &\times & & & & & & & & & & &\\
      0--10 & H & &\times & & &\times & & &\times & &\times & & & & & &\\
      -1-10 & I & & & & & & & &\times & &\times & &\times & & &\times &\\
      -111- & J & & & & & & & & & &\times & & & &\times &\times &\times\\
    \end{array}
  \]
  \caption{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why do we need 18 columns for this? `@{}c l|*{16}{wc{\widthof{(16)}}}@{}` or `@{}c l|*{16}{c}@{}`

Comment: I was under the impression you also wanted to align "A", "B", "C",.... If you don't want these letters to align, just remove the `l` from `\begin{array}`, change `-0000 & A` back to `&-0000\; A` (adjust the other rows accordingly)  and switch form `&   &` to a single `&` in the beginning of all the header rows.

Comment: ok thanks. But now the problem I face is that the table moves on the next page leaving a sufficient blank page in previous. There were hardly 3-4 lines in the new page. But the table still does not fit in that page.

Comment: ok . I used `h!`. Thanks

Comment: +1. A minor thing: I think you should (a) use text rather than math mode for the first column and (b) replace the few instances of `--` in the first column with `-{}-` (or `-\kern0pt-` in case you use LuaLaTeX) in order to avoid getting en-dashes.

Comment: @Mico there's no way to use text. Because it is entirely a mathematical table.

Comment: @ManjoyDas - You claim, "There's no way to use text." My suggestion apparently wasn't clear enough. I meant to suggest that you use text *mode* rather than math mode for the first column. (Note the additional word "mode".) This may be achieved easily by changing the specifier of the first column from `c` to `>{$}c<{$}`.

Answer (score 3):

Other than for the `\times` directives, there doesn't appear to be a compelling reason for using math mode for the table at hand.

Here's a solution that lets you use either `\times` or `\checkmark`, employs a `tabular*` environment to set the table's width to `\textwidth` automatically, and uses a monospaced font for the material in the very first column. Observe that one needn't employ `\footnotesize` in order to get the table to fit; `\small` will do just fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,array,booktabs,calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\chmk}{$\times$} % or: \newcommand{\chmk}{\checkmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} >{\ttfamily}l @{\,} r @{\,} *{16}{wc{\widthof{(16)}}}}
      & & (1) &(2) &(3) &(4) &(5) &(6) &(7) &(8) 
        & (9) &(10 &(11)&(12)&(13)&(14)&(15)&(16) \\ \addlinespace
      & & 0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &1 &1\\
      & & 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1\\
      & & 0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1 &1\\
      & & 0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1\\
      & & 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1\\ \midrule
      -0000 & A & \chmk & & & \chmk \\
      1000- & B & & & & \chmk & & & \chmk \\
      01-01 & C & & & & & & \chmk & & & \chmk \\
      10-01 & D & & & & & & & \chmk & & & & \chmk \\
      011-1 & E & & & & & & & & & \chmk & & & & & \chmk \\
      111-0 & F & & & & & & & & & & & & & \chmk & & \chmk \\ \addlinespace
      00--0 & G & \chmk & \chmk & \chmk & & \chmk \\
      0--10 & H & & \chmk & & & \chmk & & & \chmk & & \chmk \\
      -1-10 & I & & & & & & & & \chmk & & \chmk & & \chmk & & & \chmk \\
      -111- & J & & & & & & & & & & \chmk & & & & \chmk & \chmk & \chmk\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A variant of Mico's answer without typewriter type. Instead I define a declaration `\shortminus` by which the hyphen will be turned into a minus sign as wide as the digits.

A local command `\?` for `$\times$` is used, so the coding is easier.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,graphicx,booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shortminus}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`- \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\short@minus
  \mathcode`-="8000
}
\newcommand{\short@minus}{%
  \resizebox{\fontcharwd\textfont0`\0}{\height}{$\m@th\std@minus$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\?}{$\times$} % local command for easier coding

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  >{$\shortminus}l<{$}
  c @{\quad}
  *{16}{w{c}{1em}}
}
\toprule
      &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &10 &11 &12 &13 &14 &15 &16 \\
\cmidrule{3-18}
      &   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
      &   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &   & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &   & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\midrule
-0000 & A &\? &   &   &\? &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
1000- & B &   &   &   &\? &   &   &\? &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
01-01 & C &   &   &   &   &   &\? &   &   &\? &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
10-01 & D &   &   &   &   &   &   &\? &   &   &   &\? &   &   &   &   &   \\
011-1 & E &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &\? &   &   &   &   &\? &   &   \\
111-0 & F &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &\? &   &\? &   \\
00--0 & G &\? &\? &\? &   &\? &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
0--10 & H &   &\? &   &   &\? &   &   &\? &   &\? &   &   &   &  &    &   \\
-1-10 & I &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &\? &   &\? &   &\? &   &  &\?  &   \\
-111- & J &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &\? &   &   &   &\? &\? &\? \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Some caption text}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The table fits the standard size.

[image]